# Is it possible to know whether an android phone has OTG support without rooting?

Tags: android

***Is it possible to know whether an android phone has OTG support without rooting? If so how?*** I am asked to check some information before developing an app for android.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download a USB On-The-Go checking application from Google Play.

This one below for instance doesn't require root, although it does require that you follow the exact plugging and unplugging steps.

Before I give you the link thought, I must warn you that this app asks for way too many permissions and can display very intrusive ads that can draw themselves on top of other apps. **If you install [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.usbotgchecker), definitely uninstall it and get rid of it as soon as you're done with it.**

Another thing you could do is just google for the exact model name. That kind of information is usually included in the specs, in the pdf specs, in wikipedia, or in some tear-down blog. If the specs won't even tell you the usb version number at the very least, then you'll know to keep on looking.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your quick feedback